# how to make django queryset with variable

Tags: python, django

I have a django model with a boolean field named `status`

a normal query goes like:

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(status=True)
```

but in some cases , I need to use this way:

```py
fieldname = 'status'
MyModel.objects.filter(${fieldname}=True) # wrong syntax
```

how to write this. thanks

Comment: You can use django-filter if you have many variables that you need to manage. https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply,

```
fieldname = 'status'
MyModel.objects.filter(**{fieldname:True})
```

Comment: Thanks. i just don't really understand this `**` syntanx

Comment: You can read more regarding the same here about that concept, [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: In short, this is what we call ***dictionary unpacking***

Comment: Is there a way to do it without including `True`? Just `fieldname` as variable.

Comment: Here the `True` is the value to be filtered, you can use any value